how to utilize the react-native-vision-camera library to detect faces from a static image URI
The FaceDetector from expo-face-detector has been marked as deprecated in sdk 51 and the official expo documentation recommends to use react-native-vision-camera.
Below is my old function:
import * as FaceDetector from 'expo-face-detector';

 const detectFaces = useCallback(async (imageUri: string) => {
    try {
      const options = {
        mode: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorMode.fast,
        detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorLandmarks.none,
        runClassifications: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorClassifications.none,
      };
      return await FaceDetector.detectFacesAsync(imageUri, options);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(" ~ file: SeancePhoto.tsx ~ line 54 ~ detectFaces ~ error", error)
    }
  }, [],)

I saw how we can detect faces on frames using react-native-vision-camera but not on images whose URI we could provide.
